# Magento 1.7 REST API nginx rewrite rule. api.php no executed

Tags: api, magento, rest, nginx, url-rewriting

all
If I open the link http://example.com/api/rest/products, it just downloaded api.php, and not the script is executed.

what can it be?

there is my nginx rules for magento site

```
location /api {
  rewrite ^/api/rest /api.php?type=rest break;
}
location / {
    index index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
    expires 30d;
}

location ~ (/(app/|includes/|lib/|/pkginfo/|var/|report/config.xml)|/\.svn/|/.hta.+) {
             deny all;
}

  location ^~ /(app|includes|lib|media/downloadable|pkginfo|report/config.xml|var)/ { internal; }
  location /var/export/ { internal; }
  location /. { return 404; }
  location @handler { rewrite / /index.php; }
  location ~* .php/ { rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last; }
  location ~* .php$ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
    expires off;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I saw that post, too, and got the same thing.
I changed the rule from `break` to `last` and things seem to work now:

```
location /api {
  rewrite ^/api/rest /api.php?type=rest last;
}
```

I believe it works this way because `last` re-scans the rewrites and can execute your '.php' location directive, where `break` only considers the current location block (/api). Source: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite

Answer (score 4):

you should write this in your nginx configuration:

```
   location /api 
    {
    rewrite ^/api/rest /api.php?type=rest last;
    rewrite ^/api/v2_soap /api.php?type=v2_soap last;
    rewrite ^/api/soap /api.php?type=soap last;
    }
```